# separate css for one Angular2 page of app

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 app which has a theme. I copied the theme css and js to an assets folder and included them in index.html. They are now applied to every web page in the app. I also have API online documentation, which has it's own (static - generated by scripts) html page with its own css and its own js. The overall theme css and the documentation css don't play nice together and cannot be both included in index.html. How do I link to my static documentation html page without bringing in the main site theme css and js?

After receiving the same responses, I should mentioned that I did look into styleUrls and it didn't help. It means that for every component that I have which has a template I should include the same styleUrls, except for the documentation component, where I should include the other css in the styleUrls. I don't want to do that because it becomes a maintenance nightmare. Also, I have several css for the main theme, so it makes it even harder to replicate that statement across tens of files (hundreds in the future).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'live-auction',
    templateUrl: 'live-auction.html',
    styleUrls: []   <<= inject your template css files here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your static documentation html page is a component that just shows a view, you can apply encapsulated CSS to that component's view using the styleUrl attribute in the @Component header.

```
@Component{
...
...
styleUrls: ['./path/to/style.css']
}
export class StaticApiDocumentation{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external stylesheet you can include it to your app component using **styleUrls** property in the @Component decorator

```
 styleUrls: ['src/app.component.css'],
```

If you want to use inline styles then you can use **styles** in the @Component decorator

```
styles: ['h1 { color: blue; }']
```

Also you can combine them to achieve the expected result as below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['src/app.component.css'],
  template: `
    <div>
    <h1> this is H1 tag</h1>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
   styles: ['h1 { color: blue; }']

});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hd269mE2GBVievXgzhCF?p=preview)**

**Note**: In your case, since you are using a template, you will have to include the stylesheet in the template in your AppComponent so that it is available to all the components because AppComponent will be the parent to all. Alternatively, you can directly include the css reference using

```
<link href="path_for_Stylesheets" rel="" />
```

into your index.html which is the common way of including style sheets.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. That's because assets/documentation.component.css overlaps with assets/main.css. index.html has assets/main.css included. How can I exclude assets/main.css only for the documentation page (which could have styleUrls=['assets/documentation.components.css'])?

Comment: Can you add ur code to your post so that I can try fixing it